# Users that played in X different dates - SQL Standard + BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following schema of a data model (I only have the schema, not the tables) on BigQuery with SQL Standard.

I have created this query to select the Top 10 users that generated more revenue in the last three months on the Love game:

```
SELECT
  users.user_id,
  SUM(pay.amount) AS total_rev
FROM
  `my-database.User` AS users
INNER JOIN
  `my-database.IAP_events` AS pay
ON
  users.User_id = pay.User_id
INNER JOIN
  `my-database.Games` AS games
ON
  users.Game_id = games.Game_id
WHERE
  games.game_name = "Love"
GROUP BY
  users.user_id
ORDER BY
  total_rev ASC
LIMIT
  10
```

But then, the exercise says to only consider users that played during 10 different days in the last 3 months. I understand I would use a subquery with a count in the dates but I am a little lost on how to do it...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Those back-ticks are not ANSI/ISO SQL standard compliant...)

Comment: I am using Google BigQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** You need to count distinct dates, not transactions, so in the qualify clause you'll need to state `COUNT(DISTINCT date_) OVER ...` instead of `COUNT(transaction_id) OVER ...`. Fixed the code already.

As far as I understood, you need to count the distinct transaction_id inside IAP_Events on a 3 previous months window, check that the count is greater than 10, and then sum the amounts of all the users included in that constraint.

To do so, you can use [BigQuery's analytic functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/analytic-function-concepts), aka window functions:

```
with window_counting as (
  select
    user_id,
    amount
  from 
    iap_events
  where
    date_ >= date_sub(current_date(), interval 3 month)
  qualify 
    count(distinct date_) over (partition by user_id) > 10
  
),
final as (
  select
    user_id,
    sum(amount)
  from
    window_counting
  group by
    1
  order by
    2 desc
  limit 10
)
select * from final
```

You will just need to add the needed joins inside the first CTE in order to filter by game_name :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I needed the total revenue, but the rest is totally perfect!! Thanks for everything :)

Comment: No worries! Btw, check the code again because I was counting transactions instead of different dates. The QUALIFY clause will now filter out all those users that played less than 10 different days :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I ask what does the partition by? It's the very first time I see it.

Comment: Added link to a resource for you to learn about analytic functions.